# C# read from text file and store in variables

Tags: c#

I have a text file that reads

```
 1 "601 Cross Street College Station TX 71234"
 2 "(another address)"
 3 ...
 .
 .
```

I wanted to know how to parse this text file into an integer and a string using C#. The integer would hold the S.No and the string the address without the quotes.

I need to do this because later on I have a function that takes these two values from the text file as input and spits out some data. This function has to be executed on each entry in the text file.

If i is an integer and add is the string, the output should be

```
a=1; add=601 Cross Street College Station TX 71234  //for the first line and so on
```

As one can observe the address needs to be one string.

This is not a homework question. And what I have been able to accomplish so far is to read out all the lines using

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\KS\Documents\input.txt");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a nice project. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Did you try googling? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx

Comment: This sounds like homework to me.  Stack Overflow is not a place to do your homework for you but we ARE more than happy to help you when you get stuck.  What have you attempted so far?

Comment: have a look at [Regexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: @DavidL This is not homework question

Comment: It's worth noting that some addresses contain a number that is not an integer, like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=Boston_Athenæum+address).  Also, an address for a subunit may have a letter on the end.  You sure you want to store this stuff in an integer variable?

Answer (score 3):

I would need to see more of your input data to determine the most reliable method.

But one approach would be to split each address into words. You can then loop through the words and find each word that contains only digits. This will be your street number. You could look after the street number and look for S, So, or South but as your example illustrates, there might be no such indicator.

Also, you haven't provided what you want to happen if more than one number is found.

As far as removing the quotes, just remove the first and last characters. I'd recommend checking that they are in fact quotes before removing them.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do what you suggested using Regex.split

Answer (score 0):

From your description, every entry has this format:

```
[space][number][space][quote][address][quote]
```

Here is some quick and dirty code that will parse this format into an int/string tuple:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System.Linq;

static Tuple<int, string> ParseLine(string line)
{
    var tokens = line.Split(); // Split by spaces
    var number = int.Parse(tokens[1]); // The number is the 2nd token
    var address = string.Join(" ", tokens.Skip(2)); // The address is every subsequent token
    address = address.Substring(1, address.Length - 2); // ... minus the first and last characters
    return Tuple.Create(number, address);
}
```